# Crashlytics on Android - can't capture logcat

Tags: android, logcat, crashlytics

I have been using ACRA for reporting my crashes with my Android app but have noticed something odd recently where analytics reported crashes, but ACRA was not reporting anything.

I decided to try Crashlytics and was able to get it going with Eclipse with no problems and then forced a crash to confirm the integration was working. When I looked at the crash report on the Crashlytics site I could not find any reference to the logcat output.

Does Crashlytics have the ability to capture logcat?  I could not find any reference to this capability on their website.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/Ereza/LogcatReporter